# Good tips and tricks to "streamlining" your Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression

Obviously you have the basic Minify and Packer techniques...

But I wondered if there are any little Javascript techniques for smaller code (like those alternative if statements with `?` and `:` etc in them).

THEN, once I have nice streamlined code (...) I will minify/pack it up

Comment: tricks are nice, but how about maintainability and readability? these should be taken into account as well. big web JS projects can be very hard to maintain and hand over without them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A very good technique to help minifiers, is to pass variables into a self invoking function:

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined) {
      // all of your application logic goes in here
}(window, window.document, jQuery));
```

A minifier will then create shortcuts for the arguments, like `a, b, c, d`.

```
(function(a, b, c, d) {
}(window, window.document, jQuery));
```

Now, `window`, `document` and `jQuery` (if it's used) and the `undefined value` are accessed quite often normally. This  will help to decrease the filesize even more.

A few nice Javascript shortcuts, are described in [this **article**](http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2010/11/about-javascript-shortcuts-trickery.html).

For instance, use `~~` instead of `Math.floor()`.

```
var floored = Math.floor(55.2115);  // = 55
```

```
var floored = ~~(55.2115);  // = 55
```

---

Another really neat thing is, that almost all Javascript interpreters convert numbers for you. For instance, we want to have a `setTimeout` which fires after 3 minutes. Instead of doing it like

```
setTimeout(function() {
}, 180000);
```

or `60 * 3 * 1000`, we can just call:

```
setTimeout(function() {
}, 18e4);
```

Which probably makes much more sense, on much bigger numbers, but anyway :-)

Comment: +1 Otherwise, global objects can not be renamed.

Answer (score 10):

What I like is

```
for(var i = arr.length;i--;)
```

It does not save that much code, but has two advantages:

- access `.length` only once
- "faster" than a traditional `for` loop

But it only works if the processing order of the array does not matter.

---

I think what probably everyone knows is how to set default values, using logical OR:

```
function(must, option) {
    option = option || "defaultValue";
}
```

If `option` is not set, it is `undefined` which evaluates to `false`. JavaScript returns the value of the variable that fulfills the expression (or the value of the last one if the expressions is unfulfilled, I think). Of course it depends on which values `option` can have, i.e. this would not work if one possible value is `false`.

---

A fast way to convert number strings to numbers is by prepending `+`. There is no need to use e.g. `parseInt`:

```
var n = +"123";
// instead of `var n = parseInt("123", 10)`
```

Comment: Nice ^_^ - This is exactly the sort of tips I am looking for!

Comment: I thought it was only faster because it doesn't query `.length` on every iteration, as increment/decrement difference will be effectively 0 in JavaScript?

Comment: I guess a reversed while loop is the fastest loop you can create.

Comment: @Piskvor: Evaluating the condition is also easier (faster) as the value has only to be compared against `0`. I  put faster in quotes because it probably makes only a difference for large arrays. @jAndy: Yes, a `while` loop is most likely the fastest. But I think a `for` loop is more expressive.

Comment: +1 @FelixKling really like the explantion on `option = option || "defaultValue";` now i know why sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: One problem with using `option || 'defaultValue'` is if the option is supposed to be false. Then you will get the default value instead of the false value.

Comment: @goldenratio: Which is why I said *"Of course it depends on which values `option` can have, i.e. this would not work if one possible value is `false`."*

Comment: Ah my mistake, I must have missed that part.

Answer (score 3):

None worth the hassle - with minification and gzip, saving one character here and two there is definitely unnecessary microoptimization. You may save a few bytes, yes, maybe even a hundred or two, but at the expense of your dev time, when you could be making something awesome.

Comment: I kind of agree with you - but at the end of the day - smaller code is faster... Generally...

Comment: @Neurofluxation: [citation-needed]. Silly counter-example: you could compress the code and then run a decompressor on it - it will be smaller *and* slower, due to the decompression overhead. Anyway, if you're coding a for-fun project, by all means, do spend time on the legendary 97% of microoptimizations - it will be a learning experience, but don't delude yourself that it's a major feature. If I'm coding for someone else, I would have a hard time justifying time expended that way (unless the goal is indeed optimization - Google may care to shave 2 bytes off its main page, due to its traffic).

Comment: Understood - good arguement :) I just like optimisation! *+1*

Comment: You can end up making things harder for yourself if you minimize all variables to one letter, and make functions cryptic etc. As I noted in my answer... I'm more in favor of writing it clean and comprehendible to start, then let my "compiler" take care of the micro-optimizations for me.

Comment: @Neurofluxation: Me too, but since I managed to delay a project with it, I'm a bit more careful :D

Answer (score 1):

I would just write the code in a clear readable manner then use Google closure or similar to optimize and compress it.

http://code.google.com/closure/

Quote from the Closure site:

> The Closure Compiler compiles JavaScript into compact, high-performance code. The
>   compiler removes dead code and rewrites and minimizes what's left so that it downloads and
>   runs quickly. It also checks syntax, variable references, and types, and warns about common JavaScript pitfalls.

Comment: Yeah, I've used this - But I'd rather avoid compression - want to make my code readable as it's a learning experience

Comment: @Neurofluxation: Then do what jQuery does - IIRC, you can choose between jquery.js and jquery.min.js: keep the normal code, and also have the compressed/minified code for cases where size matters.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Make your code that you write and maintain readable, then let Closure optimize the heck out of it.  I probably shouldn't have said "compress" because that's not really what is going on... Closure inspects your code and applies the optimizations that make it fast, and small.  As for compression, let gzip do that on your server.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (conditional && conditional) {
    doSomething();
}
```

can become:

```
conditional && conditional && doSomething();
```

Comment: @Neuro: Sure (http://jsfiddle.net/Sxv6E/), the key is the final "&&"

Comment: Love it! - damn character limit

Answer (score 1):

This is an admirable idea. But I think it is more important that the code is readable, understandable and maintainable, than being optimized for size. The whole of the minified version of jQuery 1.5 is only 85kB in size. This is smaller than many images on a lot of websites.

A lot of people write code like:

```
$('a#click_me').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).children('img').hide();
    ... etc...
    $(this).parent().addClass('xyz');
});
$('a#click_me').css('width',  '10px');
$('a#click_me').css('height', '10px');
```

instead of:

```
$('a#clickme').css({width: '10px', height: '10px'}).click(function(){
    var $this = $(this), href=this.href;
    $('img', this).hide();
    ... etc ...
    $this.parent().addclass('xyz');
});
```

i.e. use maps `({a: b, c: d})` where possible (e.g. in `css()` above).

Use chaining `$(selector).method1().method2()`.

Use e.g. `$('img', this)` rather than `$this.children('img')`;

Don't continually use the same selector, store the result in a variable (e.g. `$this`).

Where appropriate use the JavaScript element, rather than the jQuery one e.g.

```
href = this.href;   rather than   href = $(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: I'm persistently keeping copies of my uncompressed code :)